# Is there a way to display or list out all parent containers of a child control?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, resharper, parent

Instead of writing out

```
var parentContainer0 = this.Parent;
var parentContainer1 = parentContainer0.Parent;
var parentContainer2 = parentContainer1.Parent;
```

is there a better way to list out all the layers of parent containers?

Comment: your 3 variables point to the same object. this makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a sequence of all ancestors you can write an iterator block to easily compute it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAncestors (Control control)
{
    var current = control.Parent;
    while (current != null)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.Parent;
    }
}
```

If you want the N-th generation parent you can use `ElementAt` on this sequence, using LINQ:

```
var grandparent = someControl.ElementAt(2);
```

Comment: @HighCore I wouldn't use it enough to justify it.  Were it to be something used frequently enough in certain contexts, I'd consider it.  In the end readers are free to make that trivial alteration though.

Comment: This is definitely useful, thank you. I'm wondering what would be the best way, if possible, create a list of all the parents. some of my controls are layered deep within a varying amount of containers, and I am not always sure how many levels I need to go up nor do I know which containers are there.

Comment: @ErnestSoeralaya This will create a sequence of all parents.  To get a list, simply call `ToList` on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Control> layers = new List<Control>();
Control currentLayer = this.Parent;
while (currentLayer != null)
{
   layers.Add(currentLayer);
   currentLayer = currentLayer.Parent;
}
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, that was obvious, just wanted to write the concept ;)